# Whats the order of adjectival elements before the nouns?

Tags: adjective-order

if there are all the elements which can be adjective before a noun, can you give me how should i put them in the right position in order? if there a rule or a good example i can follow?

Comment: This is a surprisingly complex issue that on one hand does not have hard and fast rules but on the other hand will have a sentence sound natural or unnatural to people in ways that they can’t explain. It has been discussed fruitfully on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order).

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, I totally missed that "ELU" was a link in your comment.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide. It's the most complete one I've seen.

[Order of English Adjectives](http://www.grammar.cl/english/adjectives-word-order.htm)